# Trying to access second site dashboard on a multisite configuration proceeds to an error

Tags: multisite, redirect, dashboard

Having this issue that I create a sub-site and when I try to access the dashboard of that sub-site it leads to this error

This page isn’t working
domain.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

.htaccess

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#add a trailing slash to /wp-admin

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>

#END WordPress
```

wp-config.php

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);

define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);

define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.com');

define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');

define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Looked to many searches of this error none helped me.
Any advice?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you want to check the new site's definition, to ensure it isn't creating a circular reference.  To get there use `http://{your-server.com}/wp-admin/network/sites.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess and wp-config.php match mine pretty closely.

It sounds like you want to check the new site's definition, to ensure it isn't creating a circular reference.  To get there use `http://{your-server.com}/wp-admin/network/sites.php`.

- Locate the site, mouse-over its title, and click the `[ Edit ]` link.
- Ensure the proper site url is entered on the first tab, in the **Site Address (URL)** field. This frequently gets truncated, or otherwise fouled up.
- Then, check the "Settings" tab.  Make sure the site address is correct in the following (SiteURL, Home, Ossdl Off Include Dirs).

If that doesn't do it, you'll need to start checking your theme and plugins.  If it comes to that, Bitnami has a pretty good [troubleshooting checklist](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/troubleshoot-wordpress-issues/).  It is written primarily as if you were a Bitnami client.  However, a clever person will overlook their proprietary info and use their checklist as a basis for thorough troubleshooting.

Good luck!

Comment: As I was closing my browser, I decided to try one more quick search.  Tom McFarlin has an article that sounds like what you have.  ["Resolving The WordPress Multisite Redirect Loop"](https://tommcfarlin.com/resolving-the-wordpress-multisite-redirect-loop/) might be just what you need!

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for the answer.One thing I saw was that on the info tab the site adress url was domain.com/sub and on settings tab on siteurl and home was domain.com/sub/ , so I changed all of them like domain.com/sub/ and looked at the link you sent but currently no fix to the problem. Will have to look for other solutions or try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to this error **if running on LightSail Instance WP MultiSite**

Issue caused by selecting -> define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
**Default out of the bag install includes the subdomain rules which need to be changed depending your setup see

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/
```

and

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/vhosts/
```

solution
see bitnami docs: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress-multisite/administration/use-directories/